# Load page and submit form inside PHP

Tags: php, curl, form-submit

I'm creating an system that uses online compiler. IDEONE give me this feature (throgh an Web Service), but with a price for an high volume of compilations.

Then I'm trying to use [codepad](http://codepad.org), but it doesn't have an Web Service... codepad has an initial page, and clicking it's submit button, apparently the same page loads (the form's action is "/")...

I'm using curl to load page, but I'm getting "Internal Server Error". This is my code: [pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/SrB6f0mg), I'm using 000webhost, I don't know if i did something wrong or if my webserver doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trued removing the TIMEOUT? or maybe extending it?

Try this maybe:

```
<html>
<div align="center">
    <form action="compilador.php" method="POST">
        <textarea id="source" name="source"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['source']) && $_POST['source'] != "")
    {
       $ch = curl_init();

 /**
 * Set the URL of the page or file to download.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://codepad.org");

 /**
 * Ask cURL to return the contents in a variable instead of simply echoing them to  the browser.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$post_data=$_POST;

        $post_data['lang'] = 'C';
        $post_data['private'] = True;
        $post_data['run'] = True;

        foreach($post_data as $key => $value)
        {
            $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }
        $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

        $result = curl_exec ($ch);

 /**
 * Close cURL session
 */
 curl_close($ch);

        echo "<br /><br />RESULT: {".$result."}";
    }

    ?>
    </form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but the reload action occurs really fast, surely above the timeout time.

Comment: The same error =(

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log"

Comment: probably because of your hosting. Do you have the free account with 000webhost? Have you got a version of WAMP/MAMP to test it on?  WAMP LINK: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: I just tryied it, and I'm getting the same "Internal Server Error" =/

Comment: make sure to enable curl. :: http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/